# CMUSphinx never recognizes any word from audio files

Tags: java, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

Sphinx doesn't seem to recognize or process audio files it accepts the audio stream spits out a empty array(SpeechResult result). I feel like there isn't any issues with the audio file i'm using because i've tried several and it doesn't work on any of them. Does anyone have a audio file that they know works? And is there anything that stands out that could be causing the stream not to produce a transcription?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
    configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
    configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.dmp");

    StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
    //recognizer.startRecognition(new FileInputStream("E:/1video/hello-5.mp3"));

    File file = new File("E:/1video/bargain_not.wav");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    //is = AutomaticSpeechRecognition.class.getResourceAsStream("/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/aligner/10001-90210-01803.wav");
    recognizer.startRecognition(is);
    SpeechResult result = null;
    while((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
        System.out.println(result.getResult()); 
        System.out.println(result.getHypothesis());

        System.out.println(result.getWords()); 
    }
    //result = recognizer.getResult();
    //System.out.println(result);
    //System.out.println(result.toString());
    //System.out.println(result.getWords());
    /*for (WordResult wordResult : result.getWords())
    {
        System.out.println(wordResult);
    }*/
    recognizer.stopRecognition();


}
```

Here's the output from running it -- it doesn't seem to have any failures

```
 09:31:13.430 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: *+NSN+
 09:31:13.433 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: *+SPN+
 09:31:13.433 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AA
 09:31:13.434 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AE
 09:31:13.434 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AH
 09:31:13.434 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AO
 09:31:13.434 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AW
 09:31:13.434 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: AY
 09:31:13.434 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: B
 09:31:13.434 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: CH
 09:31:13.434 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: D
 09:31:13.434 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: DH
 09:31:13.434 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: EH
 09:31:13.435 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: ER
 09:31:13.435 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: EY
 09:31:13.435 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: F
 09:31:13.435 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: G
 09:31:13.435 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: HH
 09:31:13.435 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: IH
 09:31:13.435 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: IY
 09:31:13.435 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: JH
 09:31:13.435 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: K
 09:31:13.435 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: L
 09:31:13.435 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: M
 09:31:13.436 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: N
 09:31:13.436 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: NG
 09:31:13.436 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: OW
 09:31:13.436 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: OY
 09:31:13.436 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: P
 09:31:13.436 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: R
 09:31:13.436 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: S
 09:31:13.436 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: SH
 09:31:13.436 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: T
 09:31:13.436 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: TH
 09:31:13.436 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: UH
 09:31:13.437 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: UW
 09:31:13.437 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: V
 09:31:13.437 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: W
 09:31:13.437 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: Y
 09:31:13.437 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: Z
 09:31:13.437 INFO unitManager          CI Unit: ZH
 09:31:14.014 INFO autoCepstrum         Cepstrum component auto-configured      as follows: autoCepstrum {MelFrequencyFilterBank, Denoise,      DiscreteCosineTransform2, Lifter}
 09:31:14.030 INFO dictionary           Loading dictionary from: jar:file:/C:/Users/Kevin/.m2/repository/edu/cmu/sphinx/sphinx4-data/1.0-SNAPSHOT/sphinx4-data-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict
 09:31:14.132 INFO dictionary           Loading filler dictionary from: jar:file:/C:/Users/Kevin/.m2/repository/edu/cmu/sphinx/sphinx4-data/1.0-SNAPSHOT/sphinx4-data-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us/noisedict
 09:31:14.132 INFO acousticModelLoader  Loading tied-state acoustic model from: jar:file:/C:/Users/Kevin/.m2/repository/edu/cmu/sphinx/sphinx4-data/1.0-SNAPSHOT/sphinx4-data-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us
 09:31:14.133 INFO acousticModelLoader  Pool means Entries: 16128
 09:31:14.133 INFO acousticModelLoader  Pool variances Entries: 16128
 09:31:14.133 INFO acousticModelLoader  Pool transition_matrices Entries: 42
 09:31:14.133 INFO acousticModelLoader  Pool senones Entries: 5126
 09:31:14.133 INFO acousticModelLoader  Gaussian weights: mixture_weights. Entries: 15378
 09:31:14.133 INFO acousticModelLoader  Pool senones Entries: 5126
 09:31:14.133 INFO acousticModelLoader  Context Independent Unit Entries: 42
 09:31:14.133 INFO acousticModelLoader  HMM Manager: 137095 hmms
 09:31:14.134 INFO acousticModel        CompositeSenoneSequences: 0
 09:31:14.134 INFO largeTrigramModel    Loading n-gram language model from: jar:file:/C:/Users/Kevin/.m2/repository/edu/cmu/sphinx/sphinx4-data/1.0-SNAPSHOT/sphinx4-data-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.dmp
 09:31:14.807 INFO largeTrigramModel    1-grams: 19794
 09:31:14.807 INFO largeTrigramModel    2-grams: 1377200
 09:31:14.807 INFO largeTrigramModel    3-grams: 3178194
 09:31:15.582 INFO lexTreeLinguist      Max CI Units 43
 09:31:15.583 INFO lexTreeLinguist      Unit table size 79507
 09:31:15.585 INFO speedTracker         # ----------------------------- Timers----------------------------------------
 09:31:15.585 INFO speedTracker         # Name               Count   CurTime   MinTime   MaxTime   AvgTime   TotTime   
 09:31:15.586 INFO speedTracker         Load Dictionary      1       0.1020s   0.1020s   0.1020s   0.1020s   0.1020s   
 09:31:15.586 INFO speedTracker         Load LM              1       0.6730s   0.6730s   0.6730s   0.6730s   0.6730s   
 09:31:15.586 INFO speedTracker         Compile              1       0.7760s   0.7760s   0.7760s   0.7760s   0.7760s   
 09:31:15.586 INFO speedTracker         Load AM              1       1.5450s   1.5450s   1.5450s   1.5450s   1.5450s   
 09:31:15.608 INFO speedTracker            This  Time Audio: 1.94s  Proc: 0.01s  Speed: 0.00 X real time
 09:31:15.608 INFO speedTracker            Total Time Audio: 1.94s  Proc: 0.01s 0.00 X real time
 09:31:15.609 INFO memoryTracker           Mem  Total: 454.75 Mb  Free: 262.35 Mb
 09:31:15.609 INFO memoryTracker           Used: This: 192.40 Mb  Avg: 192.40 Mb  Max: 192.40 Mb
 09:31:15.610 INFO largeTrigramModel    LM Cache Size: 0 Hits: 0 Misses: 0
 <s> </s>
```

Comment: Audio file that works is included in the demo. Your file is not recognized because it has wrong format most likely. It has to be 16khz 16bit mono MSWAV file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Nikolay Shmyrev said the file must be 16khz 16bit mono MSWAV.  Such a file can be recorded with Audacity.
[image: 16Khz and mono]

File export and make sure you pick WAV (Microsoft) signed 16 bit PCM.